# changing a record to a different area

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I hope yo can point me in the right direction.

I have a SSRS report organized by Continent/Country/Customer and I need to change (force?) some of the customers to appear in a different region/country from the DB. ie:

I have a local NZ customer in the right Region/Country (australasia/New Zealand) but I want this one to show up in a different Region/Country namely (Asia/China) as this customer buys locally but exports all to China.

There are some others customers that needs to be manually organized, following the same criteria, of course.

any idea on how can I do this? 
and will be the best option to do it through SQL-Server or SSRS?

Thanks in advance.
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a new table called something like `AreaOverride` with the following columns:

```
CustomerId
Continent
Country
```

Then link to this in your query using a left outer join and replace the Continent and Country with the overridden values if they exist:

```
Select CustomerId,
Case when AreaOverride.Continent is not null then AreaOverride.Continent else Customer.Continent end as Continent,
Case when AreaOverride.Country is not null then AreaOverride.Country else Customer.Country end as Country
From Customer
Left outer join AreaOverride On AreaOverride.CustomerId = Customer.CustomerId
```

You might want to make this a view if you are going to use it in several reports or other places.

Then whenever you need to override a customer's details you simply add a row for them in this table and the values will be overridden in your reports.

Note that if you are dealing with a vendor database rather than your own you don't want to be messing with their database structure but you can still do this by creating a new database and put the `AreaOverride` table in it. Then you add the database name to your join. For example if your database was called `MyStuff` then your join looks like this:

```
Left outer join MyStuff.dbo.AreaOveride On ...
```